# Acme-Challenge not requestable by all sub-domains?

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost, letsencrypt

I have Apache 2.4 and the following site-config for acme challenges:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /.well-known/acme-challenge /var/www/letsencrypt/challenges/

    <Directory "/var/www/letsencrypt/challenges/">
        Options -Indexes
    </Directory>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    #Redirect before other rewrite rules
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /\.well\-known/acme\-challenge/
    RewriteRule (.*) /.well-known/acme-challenge/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

The file is linked in `sites-enabled` as `000-acme-challenge.conf` so it will have first priority over all others. It only seem to work for sub-/domains where PHP is running as FPM, not where e.g. GitWeb is running as CGI.

Strange, as e.g. my GitWeb (publicly accessible) is linked as `010-git.conf` which should load it after 000 (right?).

Plus I get a rate-limit error 429 for some sites. Maybe I have to wait some time there. ;-)

All sub-/domains run as `VirtualHost` btw., including GitWeb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had permanent redirects from port 80 to 443 (with LetsEncrypt certs) which is generally a good idea when there is a HTTPS version around. These redirects caused the certificate not to be validated (of course).

A bit of a help with [this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26399826/apache-mod-alias-redirectmatch-everything-except-specific-pattern) answer (by Cherry) I was able to have both redirect and came up with this:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <VirtualHost f.haeder.net:80>
        ServerName f.haeder.net
        ServerAlias f.haeder.net
        RedirectMatch permanent ^(?!/.well-known/acme-challenge/).* https://f.haeder.net/
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

This is what I'm using on my Friendica node and as you can test for yourself, it works perfectly. Just to share this little piece of config. :-)